# Grabbing another form element and store as variable

Tags: php

Sorry for what is probably quite an easy question, but I'm trying to pick up some info from my php form:

This is my current code which works for the post name, but what if I want to also grab the colours boxes that were selected too?

main.php

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $data = $_POST['name']; // the data from the form input.
}


$colour_array = [
"red" => "#9E2A2B",
"blue" => "#3E5C76",
"green" => "#335C67",
];

?>

 ...
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Acme Corp"/>
    <input name="colour" type="checkbox" value="red">Red<br>
    <input name="colour" type="checkbox" value="blue">Blue<br>
    <input name="colour" type="checkbox" value="green">Green<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <img src="pngfile.php?data=<?php print urlencode($data);?>"
          alt="png php file">
```

I guess I confused because currently it is calling this:

pngfile.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'functions.php';  // Requires and includes do not need brackets.
   $inputData = urldecode($_GET['data']);
   process($inputData);
   exit;
?>
```

Which calls functions.php

```
<?php
function process($inputdata)
{
...
```

The issue is I want to be able to separate out the values from the form, so I get both the input box and the colour selection in separate variables.

EDIT: What I have tried:

main.php

```
 $data = $_POST['name'] && $_GET['colour']
```

functions.php

```
process($inputdata, $colours)
```

But I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: change name="colour" to name="colour[]"

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, change `name="colour"` to `name="colour[]"`

To access the value of **colour** in php do something like below

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['colour'])) {
    foreach($_POST['colour'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
    }
}
?>
```